Unable to style theme for TextFormField
I want to style my inputFormField for (First Name, Last Name and Middle Name to be the same style as the Street address
As you can see I try to style but it looks different from the field below.
I want to:

Put the label on top of the field.
Background color to grey.
Border radius to 5

Here's my style, it's not work:
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 22,
    horizontal: 26,
    ),
    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 241, 241),
    filled: true,
    border: InputBorder.none,
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: isDarkTheme ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
    ),
 ),



Try below code hope its help to you. I have created one Custom TextField class
CustomTextField
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final String heading;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool obscureText;
  final Icon? prefixIcon;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;

  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.hintText,
    this.heading = '',
    required this.controller,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(heading),
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        TextField(
          controller: controller,
          obscureText: obscureText,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: hintText,
            prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
            fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 241, 241),
            filled: true,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

UI:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom TextField Example')),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CustomTextField(
                heading: 'First Name *',
                hintText: '',
                controller: TextEditingController(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CustomTextField(
                heading: 'Last Name *',
                hintText: '',
                controller: TextEditingController(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              CustomTextField(
                heading: 'Middle Name',
                hintText: '',
                controller: TextEditingController(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Result Image
Note: You can add some parameteres as per your need in CustomTextField class like validator, suffixIcon, etc...
